Agentic Discovery & Exploration
I have been reading quite a bit or research on AI Agents, and specially have experimented  notebooks from LangChain and LlamaIndex (Agentic RAG).  I find the WebVoyager research paper particularly interesting together with the LangChain implementation.
Any other resources someone can point me to?

Any resources about what? We can't read minds, although we can guess, but that's not good. Also, what kind of resources are you looking for? Research papers? Books? Something else? Also, please, put your specific question in the title.
